# How do I export a route in react js that relies on a promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication

I am trying to do authentication in react using msal and azure b2c.  I have the redirect to the authentication page working and the callback.  I've created a component that I can use instead of Route in the router that checks if the user is authenticated and if not redirects to the login page.

PrivateRoute.tsx

```
const auth = new Auth();
export const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
<Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
    auth.isAuthenticated() === true
        ? <Component {...props} />
        : <Redirect to='/login' />

)} />)
```

AuthService.tsx

```
isAuthenticated = () => {

   this.userAgentApplication.acquireTokenSilent(applicationConfig.b2cScopes)
        .then(function (token) {
            return true;
        }, function (error) {
            this.userAgentApplication.acquireTokenPopup(applicationConfig.b2cScopes).then(function (token) {
                return true;
            }, function (error) {
                return false;
            });
        });
}
```

The problem is that this.userAgentApplication.acquireTokenSilent is a promise.  Does anyone know how to set this up as a callback or wait for the promise so that the route rendered the right component?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try with the await keyword ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await

Comment: that's an odd design.  I would launch that authentication code as soon as possible on application initialization and store the result wherever appropriate (Redux/component state) and check that value when rendering the Route.

Comment: I was following this pattern https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow